# Python SQLite INNER JOIN on column names with spaces

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, join, inner-join

I've been trying many different variations of different SQL queries to an Sqlite DB in python all day, and although I could get some of them to work, I don't know why they did or didn't work.

I can't get the below query to work. I originally used triple quotes so I could make it more readable on multiple lines, but a different query wasn't working that way until I changed it to single apostrophes, so I did the same to the below example.

```
cur.execute('select "LeadDataTable.Lead ID" AS "Lid", "LeadDataTable.Email", "LEINTable.LeadID", "LEINTable.DLin" from "LeadDataTable" inner join "LEINTable" ON "Lid" = "LEINTable.LeadID" ')
records = cur.fetchall()
print(records)
```

I've tried to use different variations of using nothing, apostrophes, quotes, and whatever `s are called. Nothing has worked so far. Currently, I get an empty array returned. I was getting an 'ambiguous column name' error, and a 'column doesn't exist' error. however, when I run the queries separately as follows, it works -

```
cur.execute('select "Lead ID" as "LeadID", Email from LeadDataTable')
records = cur.fetchall()
print(records)

cur.execute('select LeadID, DLin from LEINTable')
records = cur.fetchall()
print(records)
```

I don't know the rules of when to use which characters, and if it's specific to my coding environment/linter?

Comment: Did you try to wrap your sql command in triple quote: ''' ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"LeadDataTable.Lead ID"` is a string literal and not the value of a column.

Use double quotes (or square brackets, or backticks) only when needed.
In this case, only the column `Lead ID` needs them and in the `ON` clause you can't use the alias of `Lead ID`:

```
cur.execute('select LeadDataTable."Lead ID" AS Lid, LeadDataTable.Email, LEINTable.LeadID, LEINTable.DLin from LeadDataTable inner join LEINTable ON LeadDataTable."Lead ID" = LEINTable.LeadID')
```

or, make it more readable:

```
sql = '''
select LeadDataTable."Lead ID" AS Lid, 
       LeadDataTable.Email, 
       LEINTable.LeadID, 
       LEINTable.DLin 
from LeadDataTable inner join LEINTable 
ON LeadDataTable."Lead ID" = LEINTable.LeadID
'''
cur.execute(sql)
```